/ in parameter which will be passed in url
I am facing issue when I pass a parameter which contains / in it; the url will assume as separate route and eventually request fails.
For example - this is my endpoint:
http://domainname/ErpProductCount/{StockName}  

and url will be
http://domainname/ErpProductCount/DIN-SMS-60/90SP 

Here, DIN-SMS-60/90SP is the name of stock but url consider it as a separate path.
I tried using the EscapeDataString method:
var encodedStockName = Uri.EscapeDataString(StockName);

But it doesn't work.
BTW, I am working in a C# project.

Inside the asp.net core, you could use the *StockName as the  route constraint for your controller method.
The {*stockName} pattern tells the route to treat everything after ErpProductCount/ as part of the stockName, including any slashes.
Try this codes:
    [HttpGet("ErpProductCount/{*StockName}")]
    public IActionResult TestView(string StockName) {


        return View();  
    }

Result:

